# Adjust brightness with Autohotkey using micrsoft codes for HID

Tags: windows-8, autohotkey, brightness

I know there are similar questions but I have done some investigation and have noticed that AutoHotkey works perfectly with Volume_Up and Volume_Down but I am surprised there is no similar command for brightness which is built in Windows.

I guess the brightness control on my laptop (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd>) work without any Toshiba drivers so it's either built in the BIOS or Windows 8 software controlled.

I found this document [Keyboard Enhancements in Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn613956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I don't know how to use the codes given in the document to control brightness.

Is it possible to control the brightness using AutoHotkey?

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/83100-laptop-screen-brightness/

Comment: @crazypotato ok thanks, that actually works but it still doesn't solve the problem that it doesn't show the brightness level overlay. Is this preferred to NirCmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no Windows 8 to try tool from your link, but you can try to workaround your problem free NirCmd tool from [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

It allows to control brightness (and many other things) with command line. I'm not familiar with Autohotkey, but I guess it allows to configure hotkey to run some command line script.

Comment: yes I have already implemented this with NirCmd but it doesn't show the brightness level bar.

Comment: I think it's because brightness level bar comes from Toshiba software that catches hotkeys normally. NirCMD controls brightness control mechanism built in windows. I guess there is no display brightness bar, but I may be wrong, im not Win 8 expert.